# Get UserId using MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(); in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have an asp.net web app and i have an issue when two or more users on the same network are logged in . I use a query to retrieve account details which sometimes retrieves the details of the other person logged in on the same network.

**Example**

John are Lisa are logged in with different devices and different account on the same WiFi.

Sometime Lisa's Account Details appear as John's details on his account and same happens to lisa.

This is an example of the query

```
// Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        // Retrieve profile Name

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSql = "SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            Label1.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

I am not sure if this issue arises from

```
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

, the query or i am not doing something right.

Thank you.